# Set canvas as a "circle" - allow nothing to draw outside the circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I've created a canvas element and set it's width and height.

Then I've set the border-radius on the ID of the canvas so that the canvas looks like a circle.

However, if I draw something outside the circle area, it'll still draw it, as shown on my example code :
http://jsfiddle.net/mN9Eh/

### JavaScript :

```
<script>
function animate() {
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    if(i > 80) {
        i = 1;
    }

    if( i > 40) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(50, 50, i-40, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0033";
        ctx.fill();
    }

    i++;

    ctx.restore();

    setTimeout(animate, 10);
}

var i = 0;
animate();
</script>
```

### CSS :

```
#myCanvas {
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 300px;
}
```

### HTML :

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

I remember reading something that you can't apply CSS transformations to canvas elements as it won't know about them (i.e. setting width in the CSS instead of the element didn't work right). How would I fix my canvas element to appear as a circle that doesn't allow drawing outside the circle (or at least doesn't appear for users if drawn outside the circle).

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug, because it works in Safari 5 (Windows), Opera, Firefox, and IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the circle to create a "clipping path" for all subsequent drawing actions.

```
var cx = c.width / 2;
var cy = c.height / 2;
var r = Math.min(cx, cy);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.clip();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/MvSB2/

Note that there's a bug in Chrome which prevents the clipping mask edge from being antialiased, although it seems that your `border-radius` hack prevents that from looking as bad as it might.

Comment: That works great, didn't know it was just related to Chrome, hopefully it'll be fixed though I suppose keeping this code for future would be better

Answer (score 0):

Try using a clipping mask:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150,150,150,0,360,false);
ctx.clip();
```

Comment: cliping works but when you save canvas overflow element are also saved in image ? how to avoid overflow?